# when battery is low alert dialogbox show msg. When connect charger it show dialogbox and automatically dismiss dialogbox without any button

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is my broadcast receiver fun in `MainActivity.kt` file

```
private val mPlugInReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val bm = context.getSystemService(Application.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
        val batLevel:Int = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
        System.out.println("integerBatteryLevel ===="+batLevel)

        if(batLevel < 20){
            System.out.println("this is low battaroy below 20 % ===="+batLevel)
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("this is nice  battaroy more than 20 % ===="+batLevel)
        }
        when (intent.action) {

            Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED -> {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Power connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
dismissDialog()
               // openDialogForBatteryStatus(false)
            }
            Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED -> {
                if(batLevel > 20){
                    openDialogForBatteryStatus(false)
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Power disconnected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    openDialogForBatteryStatus(true)

                }          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first `BaseActivity` Calling Alert Dialog box:

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val d
    fun openDialogForBatteryLevel(show: Boolean){
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_battery_low, null)

        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@BaseActivity)
        dialog.setView(dialogView).setCancelable(false)

        val d= dialog.create()

        if(show){
            if(d.isShowing)
                d.show()
        }else{
            d.dismiss()
        }

        dialogView.txtViewDescription.text = "Your Phone Battery is low"

        dialogView.txtViewOk.setOnClickListener{
            this.finishAffinity()
        }

        d.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    }

    fun openDialogForBatteryStatus(show: Boolean) {
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_battery_low, null)

        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@BaseActivity)
        dialog.setView(dialogView).setCancelable(false)
        d= dialog.create()
        if(show){
            if(d.isShowing)
                d.show()
        }else{
            d.dismiss()
        }
        dialogView.txtViewDescription.text = "Please Remove charger"

        dialogView.txtViewOk.setOnClickListener{
            this.finishAffinity()

        }

        d.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    }

fun dismissDialog(){
if(d != null){
d.dismiss()
}
}
}
```

This is My Second `BaseActivity` Calling Alert Dialog box after change First File

```
fun openDialogForBatteryLevel(show: Boolean, message : String): AlertDialog{

    val dialog
    val dialogView

    var d

    if(alertD == null){
        dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@BaseActivity)
        dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_battery_low, null)
        dialog.setView(dialogView).setCancelable(false)
        d = dialog.create()
    }else{
        d = alertD
    }

    if(show){
        if(d.isShowing)
            d.show()
    }else{
        d.dismiss()
    }

    dialogView.txtViewDescription.text = message

    dialogView.txtViewOk.setOnClickListener{
        this.finishAffinity()
    }
    d.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

    return d
}
```

Comment: Thnks Philip Dukhov for edited my code any changes or more solution if possible than let me know.

Comment: what you want to accomplish here ?

Comment: less than 20 dialogbox come when i plugin dialog dismiss automatically without button click and start charging. when charging more than 70 again dialog box come to remove charger when i plugout dialog dismiss. when it is 70 than ringtone play it wont stop till i plug out cable from device.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code like this

```
private val mPlugInReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    val bm = context.getSystemService(Application.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
    val batLevel:Int = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
    System.out.println("integerBatteryLevel ===="+batLevel)

    if(batLevel < 20){
       // Show dialog here
    }
    when (intent.action) {
        Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED -> {
            // Dismiss dialog
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rajesh but i have already done this in my activity but it not getting dismiss dialog please review it once again.